# How to inset chinese characters into hive table?

Tags: hadoop, unicode, utf-8, hive, insert

I have a hive table which is created by the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test
(datetime STRING, person_name STRING)
ALTER TABLE test SET serdeproperties ('serialization.encoding'='UTF-8');
```

However, when I try to insert a test row into the table by running this:

```
insert into table test values ("2010-01-01", "啊");
```

It gives me the following error:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:51 character '<EOF>' not supported here
line 1:46 character '啊' not supported here
```

Does anyone know how to insert the value correctly? Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replaced double quotes with single, don't see any error while inserting the data.

```
hive> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test1
    > (datetime STRING, person_name STRING);
OK
Time taken: 0.058 seconds
hive> ALTER TABLE test1 SET serdeproperties ('serialization.encoding'='UTF-8');
OK
Time taken: 0.079 seconds
hive> insert into table test1 values ('2010-01-01', '啊');
Time taken: 12.456 seconds
hive> select * from test1;
OK
2010-01-01      啊
Time taken: 0.168 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Even with double quotes, There is no issue

```
hive> insert into table test1 values ("2010-01-01", "啊");
hive> select * from test1;
OK
2010-01-01      啊
2010-01-01      啊
Time taken: 0.102 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

Comment: There is no difference between single and double quotes, I always prefer to use single quotes while inserting the data, so i have added that to my answer. I tried with double quotes as well didn't face any issue... added that to my answer

Comment: @MrLister Hi, my problem is fixed using single quote. However, still unable to insert with double quotes.

Comment: @Vijiy. Sorry, it turns out that there is some display error with my hive terminal. I think both are fine. Shall I delete this post?